# Error installing VirtualBox in Kali Linux

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, virtualbox

I am trying to install VB in Kali.
I type:

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

But the output is:

```
root@kali:/# apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-5.0 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: dkms but it is not installable
                  Recommends: linux-headers but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: I encountered this same problem in Debian. It turned out that the problem was because I was running 9.2 ("stretch") but the release listed in the apt-spec was "yakkety". Are you sure that "vivid" matches your Kali version? You might want to try "buster" https://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-relationship-with-debian

Answer (score 3):

According to the official [website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) , You need to install `dkms` first:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

> Ubuntu/Debian users might want to install the `dkms` package to ensure that the VirtualBox host kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt and vboxnetadp) are properly updated if the linux kernel version changes during the next apt-get upgrade. For Debian it is available in Lenny backports and in the normal repository for Squeeze and later.

**Edit**

Kali linux  is a Debian-based distribution , to add the virtual-box source , you shoud type (not the `debian vivid`):

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jessie contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vbox.list
```

Some dependencies need to be installed :

```
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libv/libvpx/libvpx1_1.3.0-3_amd64.deb
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u2_amd64.deb
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sdl-ttf2.0/libsdl-ttf2.0-0_2.0.11-3_amd64.deb
```

Install dependiencies:

```
dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libvpx1_1.3.0-3_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libsdl-ttf2.0-0_2.0.11-3_amd64.deb
```

Assuming you have installed `dkms` and `linux-headers` , you can install the vitrualbox via command line or by downloading the `deb` as follows:

```
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.4/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.4-110228~Debian~jessie_amd64.deb
dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.4-110228~Debian~jessie_amd64.deb
```

Comment: thanks bro, I've download libs with wget and install, then use apt-get install virtualbox-5.1 and work for me :D +1